# How to convert R.drawable String to R.drawable integer format in android?

Tags: android, string, resources, integer, type-conversion

I would like to R.drawable which is in a dynamic string format currently to an integer format.How can be it done.Please guide me with a snippet on this to resolve it.Thank you.

```
Integer[] images={R.drawable.apple,R.drawable.mango,R.drawable.banana};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this

```
public int[] getIntIds(Integer[] images){
    int[] temp = new int[images.length];
    String name;
    for(int i=0; i<= images.length; i++){
        name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(images[i]);
        temp[i] = getResources().getIdentifier(name , "drawable", getPackageName());
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use this

```
String mDrawableName = "myimg";
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());
```

or

```
String imageName = "picture";
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", "package.name");
ImageView image;
image.setImageResource(resID);
```

Comment: I like it to stack up in set of Integer array like this Integer[] images={R.drawable.apple,R.drawable.mango,R.drawable.banana};

Comment: @Devangi  nice explaination..+1

Comment: @DevangiDesai say something to TheMechanic - it's all about you and why are you not including ?

Comment: This worked for me String imageName = "@drawable/picture";