# I want to use findViewById with strings as an Id

Tags: java, android, findviewbyid

I am new to Android Studio and just trying to learn new ways to code and I'm stuck right now. I would like to use a String in a findViewById for example.

```
public void BDate0(String BId, String BHistoryClass) {
        bdatum0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BId);
        bdatum0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent BDatum0 = new Intent(bethistory.this, BHistoryClass.class);
                startActivity(BDatum0);
            }
        });
    }
```

and I would like to call the BDate0 with the strings for example,

```
BDate0(BId1, BHistory1);
```

I have 10 buttons and the activity they start would be different every day.

Sorry for bad englihs it's not my native language and thank you for help in advance.

Comment: I think your question is dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13116057/4376058

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert R.drawable String to R.drawable integer format in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115914/how-to-convert-r-drawable-string-to-r-drawable-integer-format-in-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code to replace the `findViewById(..)`. This should make it possible to use a string as identifier:

```
String BId = "button1"; // for example 
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(BId, "id", getPackageName());
// finds R.id.button1
bdatum0 = (Button) findViewById(id);
```